# How to convert a sparse histogram into dense histogram in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, histogram

I am implementing an algorithm using raw CUDA kernels, in which every threadblock needs the dense histogram of available data to that threadblock, now the question is that do I have to calculate the dense histogram from the scratch? (is it worth calculating the dense histogram at all, provided that i already have the sparse histogram which is implemented using shared memory)

I have come up with this idea of converting, I will try to elaborate my idea with example (temp and hist both are in shared memory)

```
   0,1,2,3,4,5,6... //array indexes
   4,3,0,2,1,0,5... //contents of hist[]
   0,0,2,0,0,5,0... //contents of temp[] if(hist[x]>0)temp[x]=x;
   for_every_element     //this is sequential part :(
       if(temp[x]>0)
         shift elements from index x to 256
   4,3,2,1,0,5... //pass 1 of the for loop
   4,3,2,1,5...   //pass 2 of the for loop
                  //this goes on until all the 0s are compacted
```

Now I know above is sequential in nature, but the shifting can be done with constant time (and in parallel) because threads_per_block is already set to 256, so shifting is not the main issue, the main issue is how to improve this (or any other suggestion is welcomed).

Edit: i am thinking of another idea, that is as follows
Assuming `threads_per_block=256` if i can count which of histogram bins are non-zeros (this operation is parallel because each thread is assigned to each bin, i can atomicadd the values generated by each thread) let's say that i can then start a new shared index variable `sindex=0` and each time a thread wants to store the value into `d_hist[]` it can take the latest value from sindex and store it's values to `d_hist[sindex]=hist[treadIdx.x]` after that i can atomicAdd the sindex

Now there is only one problem, there is going to be a race condition to getting the value of sindex, so i may have to setup a flag which can be locked or unlocked when a thread is adding any value to `d_hist` (but i think there can be a deadlock situation here)

Will this technique work? and is there any other technique better than that?

Answer (score 1):

Converting a sparse histogram to a dense histogram is a scatter operation.  If the sparse histogram is composed of `s_index[S_N]` and `s_hist[S_N]`, then first we create a dense histogram `d_hist[N]` composed of all zeroes (you can do this from host code, perhaps).  Then we populate the dense histogram with `d_hist[s_index[i]] = s_hist[i];`  This can be done in parallel and uses as many threads as there are valid indices in your sparse histogram (i < S_N).  Assuming your histogram is sorted, you'll get whatever coalescing benefit may be possible based on the distribution of your sparse histogram indices.

It may not make sense for your case where each threadblock is doing a separate histogram, but you may also be interested in [thrust scatter](http://thrust.github.io/doc/scatter_8h.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware of thrust scatter and gather, but i have to do this in raw CUDA kernel, though your idea is very nice but i am going to edit the original post, please have a look.

Comment: I was confused by your usage of sparse and dense.  This answer goes from sparse to dense.  In reality what you were asking for was dense to sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the simplest method is to find out which `bins>0` and after that, and exclusive scan can be done (in order to calculate the target indexes let's say `sum_array[]`) after that for all`bins>0` move to `d_hist[sum_array[threadIdx.x]-1]=s_hist[threadIdx.x]`

```
 0,1,2,3,4,5,6... //s_indexes[]

 4,3,0,2,1,0,5... //contents of s_hist[]
 1,1,0,1,1,0,1... //all bins which are > 0 = sum_array[]

 1,2,2,3,4,4,5... //inclusive_scan of summ_array[]

 //after the moving part
 0,1,3,4,6... //s_indexes[]
 4,3,2,1,5... //d_hist[]
 0,1,2,3,4... //d_indexes[]
```

The reason why I am inclined to use this pattern is because it takes log_base_2(256) time in order to calculate the sum_array plus, other than that, moving and checking parts are just constant time operations, if anyone have different idea than this, please share.

Comment: Your usage of dense and sparse is opposite of what I am familiar with.  A [sparse histogram](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/accessing-histogram-data/) only contains the nonzero values/bins.  A dense histogram contains all values (indexes) including those whose bins are zero.  In the example you are posting in this answer you are starting with a dense histogram (includes zero bins) and ending up with a sparse histogram (only includes non-zero bins).  This confused me.  You can use `thrust::copy_if` or `remove_if` to do what you are proposing here (dense to sparse, what you call sparse to dense).

Comment: Well thanks for pointing it out (but it is kind my mistake from the beginning), What I wanted to do is stream compaction of array elements (in my case it was histogram) but then I realized that inclusive scan is best known for these kind of compaction, anyway  thanks for the help I appreciate it.